# Getting query results from 2 db tables even when second table has no corresponding entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my problem: Getting query results from 2 db tables even when second table has no corresponding entries.

Here is some sample code that i use in SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT apps.id, apps.*, req.status
FROM applications AS apps, requests AS req
WHERE apps.id = {$app_id}
```

But the issue is that it will not pull up apps that do not have a request.status value/entry, so the questions is: Would it be posible to modify this simple Query to pull up results for all application.* rows even when there is no corresponding requests.status row/entry?

**EDIT BELLOW:**

so here is my new query from the feedback that i got (this works fine)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    apps.*, req.status
FROM 
    applications AS apps
    LEFT JOIN requests AS req ON (req.app_id = apps.id AND req.uid = {$user_id})
WHERE 
    apps.id = {$app_id}
```

**BUT:** When i add a new expression to the where clause to filter the request status, i get the same issue as with implicit query, i don't get results (the query is bellow)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    apps.*, req.status
FROM 
    applications AS apps
    LEFT JOIN requests AS req ON (req.app_id = apps.id AND req.uid = {$user_id})
WHERE 
    apps.id = {$app_id}
AND
    (req.status = 2 OR req.status = 5)
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Here is updated code to look at.
The issue now is that if i add a subquery, the sub query will pull up all the rows, then have NULL as value for the status column, but as soon as i add a WHERE status != 2 it just removes all the entries, shouldn't this still have all the rows with null? because null is clearly != 2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    apps . *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        apps . *, req.status
    FROM
        appstore_app AS apps
    LEFT JOIN app_user_request AS req ON (req.uid = 187 AND req.appid = apps.appid)
    WHERE
        apps.appid > 0 AND apps.company_id = 122) AS apps
WHERE
    apps.status != 2
ORDER BY apps.average_user_rating DESC
```

**FINAL EDIT**

THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP!

Here is my final query that worked for me:

```
SELECT 
    apps.*, req.status
FROM
    appstore_app AS apps
        LEFT JOIN
    app_user_request AS req ON (req.uid = {$user_id} AND req.appid = apps.appid AND (req.status IS NULL OR req.status != 2))
WHERE
    apps.appid > 0 AND apps.company_id = {$company_id}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your third query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.P. said:

> **BUT:** When i add a new expression to the where clause to filter the request status, i > get the same issue as with implicit query, i don't get results (the query is bellow)
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT 
>        apps.*,
>        req.status
> FROM applications  apps
> LEFT JOIN requests req ON req.app_id = apps.id
>                       AND req.uid    = {$user_id}
> WHERE apps.id = {$app_id}
>   AND (    req.status = 2
>         OR req.status = 5
>       )
> ```

The problem is that the `where` clause filters the results set, so your test for a `req.status` of 2 or 5 throws out anything where `req.status` is null because no row matched the table `applications`.

The general, theoretical (since nothing but a trivial implementation would ever actually do anything like this) order of operations for a `select` statement is:

- Produce the full cartesian product of each table listed in the `from` clause.
- Filter that by applying the specified `join` criteria and eliminated rows that don't pass the specified tests.
- Apply the filter criteria specified in the `where` clause, removing rows that don't pass the specified tests.
- Order the results set on the expressions specified in the `group by` clause and partitition the results set into groups.
- Collapse each such group into a single row, computing the value of all specified aggregate functions.
- Remove all columns from the results set that aren't listed in the `select` statements column list.
- Order this final results set by the columns/expressions specified in the `order by` clause.

You can do one of two things:

- change your query to test for nullity:

  ```
  where...( req.status is null OR req.status in (2,5) )...
  ```
- move the test against on `req.status` to the join criteria:

  ```
  left join requests req on req.app_id =  apps.id
                        and req.uid    =  {$user_id}
                        and req.status in (2,5)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is using an implicit cross join, selecting data from two tables without specifying a way to relate the two tables. What you really want is a left join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT apps.id, apps.*, req.status
    FROM applications AS apps
        LEFT JOIN requests AS req
            ON apps.id = req.apps_id /* Guessing on the relationship here */
    WHERE apps.id = {$app_id}
```

Once you get the syntax right, take a look at whether or not the `DISTINCT` is really necessary for this query. It may be costly overhead that can be eliminated.

**EDIT**: The section below is added in response to the edited question.

When you test a LEFT JOINed column (`req.status` in your case) in the WHERE clause, you force that join to behave as if it were an INNER JOIN. Instead, make those tests part of the join conditions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    apps.*, req.status
FROM 
    applications AS apps
    LEFT JOIN requests AS req ON (req.app_id = apps.id AND req.uid = {$user_id})
        AND  (req.status = 2 OR req.status = 5)
WHERE 
    apps.id = {$app_id}
```

Comment: yes, i thought of that too, but then the issue is that i'm getting results for rows that have req.status as NULL.

Comment: Since rows in your `applications` table don't have matching `rows` in your `requests` table, you don't actually have a status code, hence the `null` values. You need to assign some default with `coalesce`: `coalesce(req.status,-1)` to indicate that the status is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  apps.*, req.status
FROM 
  applications AS apps
  LEFT JOIN requests AS req on req.app_id = apps.id
WHERE 
  apps.id = {$app_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` will display all your applications even when no corresponding requests.status exists.

```
SELECT DISTINCT apps.id, apps.*, req.status
FROM applications apps
LEFT JOIN requests req ON req.? = applications.?
WHERE apps.id = {$app_id}
```

You need to add the column (`?`) that links both tables together.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an explicit LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT apps.id, apps.*, req.status
FROM applications AS apps
LEFT JOIN requests AS req ON apps.whatever_field_relates = req.whatever_field_relates
WHERE apps.id = {$app_id}
```

Using implicit JOINS like `FROM table1, table2` is not good practice IMO. It makes it difficult for other programmers to understand the exact nature of the JOIN at a glance without having to refer to the database schema.

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply, that works great, but i run into a problem when i add "AND req.status != 2" in the where clause, i get no results when there is no value in the the requests table.

Comment: That is because you are filtering on an item in the requests table.  This will in essence defeat the purpose of having a LEFT JOIN.  For such queries, you might as well have a regular INNER JOIN, as you would never return unmatched records on applications.

Comment: do you think it would work if i created a sub query? like so:

SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT apps.*, req.status FROM applications AS apps LEFT JOIN requests AS req ON (apps.id = req.app_id AND req.user_id = {$user_id}) WHERE apps.user_id = {$user_id}) AS applications WHERE status = 2;

Comment: @mxaddict While, once you work out the syntax errors, that query may work just fine, you are still dealing with the same issue.  How could a record in applications which does not have a matching request ever show up in a query where you are looking for a certain value in requests to be set?

Comment: what i really wanna get as results is the apps that do not have request, what can you suggest as a solution? i will post the query that i tried, with no luck, above.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT app.*,req.status 
from applications apps 
left join request as req on req.appid = apps.id
where apps.id ={$app_id}
```

Doing a left join will do the trick, I am used to TSQL syntax, but I am sure it will work in Mysql.  You need the id of your apps in both tables tought, to be able to join them.